# Programming in C++ with Xcode 4

Tags: c++, xcode

I want to use Xcode as my major complier for C++. However, I'm having a hard time starting programming. Which kind of project and target should I select if I want to write some applications with user interface?

I've been coding with Xcode for one semester but all the projects were half-done the time I saw them, so I really don't know how to start by myself. I tried the Command Line target but it did not seem to generate an application.

Sorry for asking these naive questions. Thanks for any help!

Comment: XCode is not a compiler.

Comment: @EdS.: While true, that's not really helpful. XCode *contains* a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with a barebones project by going to New -> New Project -> Application (under Mac OS X) -> Command Line Tool.  This will give you a basic main() function that you can enter code into.  This is what I use alot of the time for algorithm practice.

If you want your app to use a GUI framework, you can either choose the template that @sblom suggested and make a Cocoa Application ([here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html) is a good guide to get you started), or you could use a C++ framework such as [wxWidgets](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Creating_Xcode_projects_for_wxWidgets_applications) or Qt (usually used with it's own IDE, Qt Creator).

Note that while Cocoa is in Objective C, you could just as well program in C++ for the core functionality of your app, just make sure the implementation files have a .mm suffix.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Mac OS X -> Application -> Cocoa Application. Unfortunately, it won't exactly be in plain ol' C++, although you can use C++. You'll have to use Objective-C to make actual calls into the Cocoa Framework (well, there are ways to make the calls using straight C/C++, but that's *really* cumbersome.)

Answer (score 0):

I will highly recommend to use QT but not WX.

We use WX for years in our Valentina Studio application. And we going switch to QT asap. Reasons are that WX on MAC has weak progress. Troubles with Cocoa support. QT looks much more better choice ...